# How to use Facebook Ads Insight API with app token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am using Facebook Ads Insight API with a user token at the moment, but this user token expires (every hour for temporary token, and every 60 days for extended token) and I need to update it manually in my environment. Is there a way to use an **app token** to permanently allow access to the AdsInsight API? Otherwise, what's a programatic way to refresh the **user token**? (FYI, I use **airflow** to store the token in **admin/connections**)

For now my URL request is :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_<SECRET_AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/insights?access_token=<SECRET_TOKEN>=ad_id,ad_name,clicks,unique_clicks,inline_link_clicks,unique_inline_link_clicks&time_range={'since':'2021-01-01','until':'2021-01-05'}&time_increment=1&level=ad
```

When the `<SECRET_TOKEN>` is

- a **user token** : Data is generated correctly
- an **app token** I get an error. (See bellow)

Error when using **app token**:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'act_<SECRET_AD_ACCOUNT_ID>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "<SECRET>"
   }
}
```

Comment: No, you can not use an app token, because app tokens don’t encompass any of the specific permissions you need to access this endpoint. And no, standard user tokens can not be refreshed _without_ user interaction either. There is however something called a “business user”, the tokens issued for those do not expire (or they can be refreshed automatically, not sure which one it was), so go look into whether that applicable for your situation & app type maybe.

Comment: This link seems to talk about this, but it only mentions "page tokens"... this particular facebook app does not fetch information of a "page" but for ad account ids. I'm not sure how to proceed, it seems weird that I'll have to manually refresh the token every couple of months. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/business-login-direct

Comment: Check if that system user can be added to the ad account as well, and not just a page. If so, then you can probably use their user access token.

Comment: @CBroe, not sure how using a system user creates a permanent token?

Comment: I am not sure whether the system user token is permanent, that’s why I said go and check.

Answer (score 1):

The user tokens last 60 days, but there is a way to automatically update them through the API. Make a GET call to the following endpoint every < 60 days to refresh your user token.

```
oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=<APP_CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&fb_exchange_token=<USER_TOKEN>
```